# javax.json.stream.JsonGenerator: Output stream not usable after use of generator

Tags: java, json

I need to output JSONP from a Servlet. I am using JsonStreamer of javax.json for outputting JSON to output stream. To produce JSONP I need to surround JSON with the callback function name and parentheses required to form the callback invocation expression (**callback(** *json*, **)**).

The problem is that what ever I print to the stream after closing the JsonGenerator, is lost. So I cannot complete JSONP with the closing parenthesis. No exceptions generated, code runs ok.

Below there is the demo code in (command-line java context for easier testing).

Is this a bug or am I overlooking something?

```
package mvu.test.jsonstreamer;

import java.io.OutputStream;
import java.io.PrintStream;

import javax.json.Json;
import javax.servlet.ServletOutputStream;

public class JsonGeneratorTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        PrintStream outstream = System.out;

        outstream.print("callbackFunc(");  // shown

        Json.createGenerator(outstream)
            .writeStartArray()
            .write("a string in an array")
            .writeEnd()
            .close();

        outstream.println(");");     // THIS IS LOST
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As per `JsonGenerator.close()` [documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/json/stream/JsonGenerator.html#close--), calling the `close()` method closes the underlying output source, or, in this case, the `outstream`.

Comment: Thanks CptBartender! I read the doc but missed that point. Maybe because I did not associate "output **source**" with the output stream, which to me is more of a sink or target... I wonder why generator takes the responsibility of closing a stream opened elsewhere?